# How to play you tube video in UWP Apps

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have a requirement to play a youtube video in uwp app. I have tried using MediaPlayerElement but it gives error Unsupported Video Type. Does Anyone has an idea of how to do this in uwp apps.please share here

Comment: Y mean you pasted a youtube video link to `MediaPlayerElement `? Then `MediaPlayerElement ` can't play it,because it isn't a m3u8 or local video.

Comment: Yes any youtube url video not working

Comment: You could not directly play the video with youtube video link like @Vincent said. Maybe you could try to create a WebView in your app and then navigate to the video link inside the WebView.

Comment: Yes using web view i am able to play but in webview it is opening all webpage of youtube .But i need to play in media element or media player element

Comment: If you want to play in the media element, the youtube link won't work, It's a web link, not a media video link.

Comment: Maybe you should try to get the real youbube video m3u8 url link, then you can do it using `MediaPlayerElement`. I know a repo which implement a youtube app on Android, see https://github.com/yuliskov/SmartYouTubeTV. Maybe you can find somgthing useful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi After long research on google and suggested help here I come to a good solution using web view and IFrame , for now, this is working fine for me, if anyone has a better solution then kindly suggest.
Please find complete code here https://github.com/dharmendrasingh88/UwpWork/tree/master/Player